# How can i used column named class in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need use column named class. But class is a keyword reserved in python.

models.py:

```
class Colecao(models.Model):
       class = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,verbose_name="Classe")
```

Comment: Why don't you write it as `class_name=models.CharField(..., related_name="class")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Django will use the field’s name as the name of the database column . in your case `class` is a reserved keyword in python you cannot use it but you  can
customize the database column name for it by using [db_column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#db-column)
use it like this :

```
class Colecao(models.Model):
       class_ = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,
         db_column='class', verbose_name="Classe")
```